# Import POM transitively

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I distribute my libraries using pom file. This pom file imports other poms like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.1024</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I expect this pom to be applied on target project too (transitively), but it doesn't work like that.

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.test:test:2.2')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-schemas' (unable to resolve)
}
```

Comment: A side question: What does mean "BOM" here in this context?

Comment: BOM pom: https://dzone.com/articles/the-bill-of-materials-in-maven

Answer (score 0):

The `<scope>import</scope>` mechanism only imports the dependencyManagement, nothing else.

Comment: Not sure that I got you. aws-java-sdk-bom contains dependencies declared in dependencyManagement section, as you said. Than according to your words it should be imported. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom/1.12.171/aws-java-sdk-bom-1.12.171.pom

Comment: The entries from dependencyManagement will be imported. Note that dependencyManagement entries are not dependencies of your project. They only specify versions and scopes.